# Can StructureMap be configured so that one can use different .config settings based on whether the project was built in debug or release mode?

Tags: structuremap, ioc-container, configuration-files, web-config

I know that in StructureMap I can read from my *.config files (or files referenced by them), when I want to pass specific arguments to an object's constructor.

```
ForRequestedType<IConfiguration>()
                .TheDefault.Is.OfConcreteType<SqlServerConfiguration>()
                .WithCtorArg("db_server_address")
                .EqualToAppSetting("data.db_server_address")
```

But what I would like to do is read from one config setting in debug mode and another in release mode.

Sure I could surround the `.EqualToAppSetting("data.db_server_address")`, with `#if DEBUG`, but for some reason those statements make me cringe a little when I put them in.  I'd like to know if there was some way to do this with the StructureMap library itself.

So can I feed my objects different settings based on whether the project is built in debug or release mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StructureMap has no built-in detection of "debug" or "release" mode.

However, when you programmatically configure StructureMap via its DSL (in a Registry, or a call to Initialize() or Configure() on the container), you are using the C# language. You can do anything that C# allows. So your question becomes "is there a way in c# to conditionally run some code differently in debug mode", to which the most obvious answer will likely be the conditional compilation directives that make you feel bad.

Comment: Fair enough, I'm curious if you ever use conditional compiler directives in your structure map configuration code? Thx

Comment: No, I would prefer to use a more externally visible setting to switch configurations. Either read the compilation "debug" setting in web.config (it is exposed by some property), or an appSetting. That way I can easily switch it on or off, regardless of how the code was compiled.